# Duplicate and alter sidebar for Twenty Eleven

Tags: css, sidebar, child-theme

I'm trying to create own template including submenu instead of the regular sidebar in Twenty Eleven.

Although I manage to create and select my new template the page ends up with bad CSS.

Here is what i have done

- Copy sidebar-page.php and named it submenu-page.php
- Copy sidebar.php and named it sidebar-submenu.php

In **submenu-page.php**

Added new template name "**Sidebar left menu template**" and changed

```
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

to

```
<?php get_sidebar('submenu'); ?>
```

In In **sidebar-submenu.php**

Replaced all code with Hello World-link.

Even tough Hello World appears correctly the link is uncklickable due the div #primary is all over the page.

For unknown reason the HTML-body gets both singular and two-columns as value in the class attribute. If I edit sidebar-page with get_sidebar('submenu') everything looks and works great.

***How do I tell wordpress that my template (submenu-page.php) is two columns and not both single and two columns?***

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the layout is controlled by the .singular css class, which in turn is generated in functions.php depending on the template.
in your [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) of Twenty Eleven (if you don't have a child theme, create one first) add this code to functions.php:

```
add_filter('body_class', 'wpse_28044_adjust_body_class', 20, 2);  
function wpse_28044_adjust_body_class($wp_classes, $extra_classes) { 

if( is_page_template('submenu-page.php') ) : 
// Filter the body classes     

          foreach($wp_classes as $key => $value) {
          if ($value == 'singular') unset($wp_classes[$key]);
          }

endif; 
// Add the extra classes back untouched
return array_merge($wp_classes, (array) $extra_classes ); 
}
```

if you want to make the change in Twenty Eleven directly, edit functions.php, near the bottom (code shown after the edit):

```
if ( is_singular() && ! is_home() && ! is_page_template( 'showcase.php' ) && ! is_page_template( 'sidebar-page.php' ) && ! is_page_template( 'submenu-page.php' ) )
```

Comment: The second solution works great. I'm not able to copy functions.php to my child theme (ERROR 500). Is it safe to say the singular is default, I have to specify when not to use singular?

Thanks!